# Check if column is in a list, remove if not and add value to a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { 
        "A" : [0,0,1,1,0,1] , 
        "B" : [1,0,0,1,1,0],
        "C" : [0,0,0,1,1,0],
        "D" : [1,1,0,0,0,1]} )
```

which looks like this:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   0   1   0   1
1   0   0   0   1
2   1   0   0   0
3   1   1   1   0
4   0   1   1   0
5   1   0   0   1
```

I have a list of columns I wish to keep `allowed_columns = ["A","B"]`. This means we get rid of `C` and `D`. However, when dropping the columns, if there is a value 1, I want to note that in a new column `lost`. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
    A   B   lost    
0   0   1   1   
1   0   0   1   
2   1   0   0   
3   1   1   1   
4   0   1   1   
5   1   0   1
```

For ease of problem, we can assume that `C` and `D` cannot have value 1 simultaneously. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subset to the allowed columns, then take the max of everything you removed with `df.columns.difference`

```
df = (df[allowed_columns]
       .assign(lost=df[df.columns.difference(allowed_columns)].max(1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us do

```
df['Lost']=df[['C','D']].max(1)
df=df.drop(['C','D'],axis=1)
```

Comment: I couldn't help but answer you Q&A (-:

Answer (score 1):

#### `groupby`

```
d = dict.fromkeys({*df} - {*allowed_columns}, 'lost')
df.groupby(lambda x: d.get(x, x), axis=1).max()

   A  B  lost
0  0  1     1
1  0  0     1
2  1  0     0
3  1  1     1
4  0  1     1
5  1  0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
c = df.columns.difference(allowed_columns)
df['lost'] = df[c].any(axis=1).view('i1')
```

---

```
print(df)

   A  B  C  D  lost
0  0  1  0  1     1
1  0  0  0  1     1
2  1  0  0  0     0
3  1  1  1  0     1
4  0  1  1  0     1
5  1  0  0  1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['lost']=((df['C']==1)|(df['D']==1)).astype(int)
df.drop(['C','D'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

You can use two booleans separated by `OR` to define the values in `df['lost']`! I think it is also intuitive, because

- `(df['C']==1)|(df['D']==1)` will be `True` if you have `1` in either
  column C or column D; otherwise it will be `False`
- `astype(int)` converts `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`